# Google Таблицы. Не считает числа!

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet

Ребята, доконает меня эта гугла)) 
Не хочет прибавлять число хоть ты тресни. Я пытаюсь из ячейки достать 45 и прибавить 4..

```
    function Labor(){
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var ch = ss.getRange(3, 8).getValues();
      ch = ch+4;
       ss.getRange(3, 8).setValue(ch);
      }
```

Просто вставляет 454... Менял и формат ячейки и преобразование типов ... На примерах у других работает, у меня нет. Жесть!
Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: те, кто минусуют вопрос, убедительная просьба, пишите по какой причине ставите минус

Comment: @meine Да правильно минусуют. Ибо **не понять** источник проблемы - это ещё постараться надо...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ch = parseInt(ss.getRange(3, 8).getValues(), 10);
```

Comment: Все получилось, спс. (через for()). Но вот через forEach почему то не хочет работать.

Comment: @ToysUnderway К сожалению, в коде вопроса нет ни `for` ни `forEach` :(.